# Accent-Insensitive Alphabetization and Searching

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

I am using SQlite data in my app. when I put the 'e' character, I'd like to search every word with 'e' or 'é', 'è'in search query. Any solution to do this.

Comment: Do you want to search in fetched data (Objective-C) or in the SQLite database?

Comment: @Willeke  search data in Objective-C.